# Encapsulating Fundamental Data Types Into Classes

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, compiler-construction

Without discussing whether or not it's a good idea, What type of drawbacks (performance or otherwise) would one face if they were to encapsulate the built-in C++ data types into their own classes. For instance, similar to Java and C#, the int data type would have its own class called Int, overloading it with inline operators. Same with Single, Double, Long, etc.

Comment: Can I ask the opposite question? What would be the advantages?

Comment: As with all such "transparent" wrappers, the semantics of `operator&` are going to be a lose-lose situation.

Comment: One advantage is that you can have them inherit a base class. Int32 : Integer : Number : Object. This is potentially useful when you don't want to overload a Math class with many types when simply Integer or Real would suffice. This also allows you to add new types to a family of types, for instance adding an Int128 down the line would not affect the math class.

Comment: @Dave: So what operations would `Integer` or `Number` allow for? The way I see it there are more or less two options: Either none at all (which would make it completely worthless), or all operations are implemented as virtual methods (which would have a severe impact on performance). Besides isn't that what we have templates for?

Comment: Are you sure having them inherit a base class is an advantage? You can write type-generic code with templates, anyway. What's a Math class for? What would be the meaning of a "Math object"? If you're trying to make Java or C# out of C++, don't. I suggest you [learn C++](http://$SITEURL$/q/388242/46642) instead.

Comment: There is a reason I mentioned at the beginning that I didn't want to discuss whether or not it's a good idea. I simply want to know whether there is a way to make encapsulated data type classes work as fast as native data types. Or are there special optimization's that are made to default data types that you just can't get with classes.

Comment: I asked because I count "more code and no advantages" as a drawback.

Comment: @R.Martinho Fernandes: I've been using C++ for many years now. Along with Java and C#. I am just doing some research to get a better understanding of how C++ compilers handle internal data types vs classes. I am hoping that someone could point me to a paper about a similar topic.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Your link is dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no benefits. You cannot achieve identical behavior, nor performance.

---

Drawbacks:

- Performance will never be *faster* than built-in types. The best you'll get is a class where everything is inlined to built-in type code, although what's the point of that?
- Lots more code for no purpose
- Virtual calls have overhead
- Cannot achieve identical behavior, such as with operators (Casting primarily)
- Non-trivial constructors (Not necessarily in C++11)
- Not supported by C++ features such as template parameters
- Confusing. Nobody does this.

---

> This is potentially useful when you don't want to overload a Math class with many types when simply Integer or Real would suffice.

You have Java stuck in your head.

C++ takes the template approach:

```
template<typename A_type, typename B_type>
auto math_operation(A_type a, B_type b) -> decltype(a + b * 2) {
  return a + b * 2;
}
```

Now you have a function that works on any type that supports the correct operators. This will work for built-in types, and classes such as `Int128`.

Comment: "You have Java stuck in your head."-I wonder if there is any way to get it out? :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what behaviours you can't emulate?

Comment: Actually its C# stuck in my head, and Java stuck in Microsoft's head :-P

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I added some. If you know anything else then say so.

Comment: @Jesse The garbage collector will clear things up once he realizes how useless it is.

Answer (score 2):

Clarity will suffer, and that's it for the most part.

If you have a smart compiler, a class that simply wraps an `int` and does not change any of the operations is fairly likely to get entirely inlined.  If you don't define the constructor as explicit, you'll even be able to write `f(15)` for `void f(OurVerySpecialInt i)`.  You'd have a harder time passing your Very Special Ints to existing functions if there are any, though.

Things are very different if you mean a class hierarchy and not just a class, though.  Do you want `Numeric` to be an abstract base class and `Int` and `Double` to derive from it?  In that case, please reconsider.  Not only will you likely end up with significantly slower code, there's not really a way to make this generic and sane at the same time.

Let's consider a class `Numeric` that overloads `operator+`.  Either the operator is non-member (as it should be), and then it cannot be virtual: therefore, it must call a virtual member function of `Numeric`.  But which one?  Does `Double() + Double()` return a `Double`?  What about `Double() + Int()`?  What about `Double() + Rational()`?  In the first two cases, you can say "`Double`, of course, because of more possible values", but in the last case that doesn't work: if a `Double` is 64-bit and a `Rational` is the quotient of two 32-bit integers, you will have values in each that cannot be expressed in the other (such as positive infinity and 0.3).

In addition to that, your functions can promise very little.  What's the value of i after `Int32 i = 250; i += 250;`?  I assume it's `500`; what about `Int8 = 250; Int8 += 250;`?  What about `Numeric* p = new Int8(250); *p += 250;`.  You can't magically make `*p` bigger, so either you make that an error or you overflow; basically, if `p` is some `Numeric*`, you can't know what `*p += 50000;` will do: work as expected or overflow/error out, and you also can't know whether you're losing precision when you do `*p += 5.3`.

If you fix these errors by making the conditions more strict, you will end up with some kind of `Rational` or `BigInt` class that doesn't need any inheritance; all behaviour is so strictly specified (as it should be with mathematical entities) that deriving from it wouldn't really let you change anything.

If that's not enough of an argument, note that in the case of you giving the `Numeric` class any virtual methods, all your derived classes will have a vtable (under common implementations).  That means that every instance of your class will need a little more space than usual, and having all your numeric values be double the normal size can hurt performance a lot depending on what you're doing.